# How to dockerize a jupyer notebooks project?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, containers

I have a project composed of 6 different (but sequential) jupyter notebooks and 4 CSV files. I would like also my colleagues can try to use this project, even if they don't have python installed and maybe with another csv. Is it possible to do this by creating a docker image of this project and letting them "play" with the notebooks and the data?

Thanks

Comment: Yes totally possible, but since apparently your colleagues don't want/can't install python, why would they install docker?

Comment: You can use a shared Notebook instance in the Cloud such as Vertex AI Notebooks and enable remote shared via Service Account or install Jupyter in a shared VM.

Comment: hi @gogasca, thanks for the answer. Is vertex ai freely available? Do you know any tutorial for that?

Comment: hi @dgan, ahaha I liked your answer. They are a more business-oriented person and would like only to play with some variables. Do you know how I can do that? thanks

Comment: @Daniele sorry, I have a project doing exactly that, but goes way beyond what I consider a "regular size Stackoverflow answer"; but the idea is simple: build your python environment in Dockerfile, build your .venv for python, expose ports from container, and run your notebook with --no-browser argument... While straightforward, it can be overwhelming. You should check tutorials on internet, I randomly found this one https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-run-jupyter-notebook-on-docker-7c9748ed209f

Comment: thanks, @dgan for your precious answer!